# Unity - Visual studio doesn't show errors. In the same time I can't hit "play" because Unity says "All errors have to be fixed"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2022

If I create project outside of Unity let's say console aplication in C# I get normal errors, everything is okay.

---

For the example, script in Unity:
`float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")`

clearly doesn't have ";" but VS shows nothing. Even If I find it in file explorer and open it through VS it shows no errors. Of course Unity gives "*.cs(19,48): error CS1002: ; expected*"

---

I would give you a screenshot but I can't (10 reputation required).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio not displaying compile time errors in editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094125/visual-studio-not-displaying-compile-time-errors-in-editor)

Comment: Please include the errors from the Unity console.

Comment: @KiynL that question refers to visual studio 2010 I use 2022/2019, there is problem with both.

Comment: @KiynL But I tried that solution tho.
I have tried goin to "Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Underline errors in the editor", it got me nowhere because there wasn't "Underline errors in the editor".

I also updated my question.

Comment: Did you attempt to build the visual studio project?  `Build`>`Build Solution` (Ctrl+Shit+B).  I check on my end and it wasnt showing, but when i clicked on the console in visual studio, the dropdown switched to Entire Solution and the error showed.  Is the errors tab in the console outlined?  Perhaps it is just not show the errors due to the filter.  eg. `0 of 1 Error`

Comment: I did not tried it because VS always showed errors in realtime, but.. I can't go to **Build>Build** Solution because it's not there. In normal situation "Build" is between "Project" and "Debug" but when I open script through Unity or Unity .cs "Build" is missing.  Maybe because there is only .cs and .meta in file explorer ? Clicking on console changes nothing for me. There is a error in console tab but nothing more no outline or highlight. It can't bo Error filter because VS says "No problems found" in bottom left corner wit hgreen circle. Maybe I'm missing something obvious, I'm new to Unity.

Comment: In Unity, navigate to Edit>Preferences>External Tools.  External Script Editor should be set to Visual Studio (2019/2020).  Under that in grey, do you see "Visual Studio Editor vX.X.XXX"?  You may need to download the visual studio editor package.  [Found Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/gamedev/unity/get-started/visual-studio-tools-for-unity?pivots=windows)